# How to fetch the second occurrence of a string in a column and rename it using R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset `$Plaza` with row names as -

```
"Main Plaza 1"

"Main Plaza 2"

"Main Plaza 3"

"Main Plaza 1"

"Main Plaza 5"
```

I have to rename the second occurrence of `'Main Plaza 1'` to `'Main Plaza 1_second'`.

I have tried the following code-

```
library("dplyr")

d <- grep("Main Plaza 1", dataset$Plaza)

for(i in length(d))

{

ifelse(length(d) == 2,
       str_replace(dataset$Plaza, grep("^Main Lane Plaza 1"),
                                      "Main Lane Plaza 1(second)"), NA)
break()

}
```

I have tried multiple times with few more codes could not find the solution. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In order to add `_second` to every string that appears more than once, you can use:

```
plaza <- c("Main Plaza 1", "Main Plaza 2", "Main Plaza 3", "Main Plaza 1", "Main Plaza 5")
dups <- duplicated(plaza)
plaza[dups] <- paste0(plaza[dups], "_second")
plaza
## [1] "Main Plaza 1"        "Main Plaza 2"        "Main Plaza 3"        "Main Plaza 1_second" "Main Plaza 5"
```

In order to modify only the second occurence of "Main Plaza 1" (but leave any other repeated elements untouched), use:

```
plaza <- c("Main Plaza 1", "Main Plaza 2", "Main Plaza 3", "Main Plaza 1", "Main Plaza 5")
i <- which(plaza == "Main Plaza 1")[2]
plaza[i] <- paste0(plaza[i], "_second")
plaza
## [1] "Main Plaza 1"        "Main Plaza 2"        "Main Plaza 3"        "Main Plaza 1_second" "Main Plaza 5"
```

Comment: Thank you. Your second solution works for my problem definition.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply subset the dataframe for the rows with your desired value, then index the second occurrence, like so:

```
pizza = data.frame(Name = c("Main Plaza 1",
    "Main Plaza 2",
    "Main Plaza 3",
    "Main Plaza 1",
    "Main Plaza 5"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

pizza[which(pizza$Name == "Main Plaza 1"),][2] <- "Main Lane Plaza 1(second)"

pizza
```

Result:

```
                       Name
1              Main Plaza 1
2              Main Plaza 2
3              Main Plaza 3
4 Main Lane Plaza 1(second)
5              Main Plaza 5
```

I would definitely try to start getting used to subsetting over looping in R, almost always.

Comment: i have used the solution provided. Thank you

Comment: @ac31 Great! Can you mark the Question as answered by clicking on the checkmark beside this answer? Would be greatly appreciated!